# Acquisition of multi-channel audio data with a Raspberry Pi

Tags: audio

I would like to build an autonomous audio device with a Raspberry Pi that can record audio data from 4 different microphones/hydrophones. I want to use this to perform acoustic localization so time synchronization between channels is important. Is there an audio card compatible with  Raspberry Pi that is capable of doing this? Most card I've seen have "only" 2 channels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer assumes that you are after an I2S sound card for the Raspberry Pi rather then a USB solution. I2S sound cards connect to the GPIO header and are generally capable of lower latencies and as there are fewer chips between the audio codecs and the CPU tend to be more reliable as well.

[ELinux has an incomplete list](https://elinux.org/RPi_Expansion_Boards#Sound) of audio sound cards for the Raspberry Pi. However as you mention there are very few with multichannel capability.

One sound card for the Raspberry Pi with multichannel capability is the [Audio Injector Octo sound card](https://www.audioinjector.net/rpi-octo-hat). It has six inputs and eight outputs. It supples RCA connectors for the inputs and outputs of the sound card. It also gives access to an analogue breakout header which allows you to design and implement your own preamplifiers and connectors for the microphones and hydrophones. The passive RCA connectors are [available for cloning and adaptation](https://github.com/Audio-Injector/AudioInjector.Octo.RCA), as are a set of [active balanced preamplifiers](https://github.com/Audio-Injector/AudioInjector.Octo.balanced). [There is also a template](https://github.com/Audio-Injector/AudioInjector.Octo.template) to assist you in implementing your own preamplifiers or passive connections.

Inputting multichannel audio to the Pi is a challenging task as the I2S bus is stereo. There are several techniques used to mitigate channel swapping. A 100% reliable method used with the Octo is to detect the empty channels on the input (2 of 8 input channels) which aren't populated. Once detected, the audio is aligned in software. [This gtkIOStream implementation demonstrates the channel alignment technique](https://github.com/flatmax/gtkiostream/blob/master/test/ALSAFullDuplexMinScan.C#L49-L70). Other channel swapping mitigation techniques can be found on the forums or the Audio Injecto email list. These other techniques include starting the soundcard using a jackd server and never stopping it as it always starts with channels aligned correctly and a similar approach can be taken with ALSA software where the audio continuously runs.